# In-App-Purchase behaviour using a real Apple ID

Tags: ios, ios8, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

### Clarification

I know, there are tons of questions about In-App-Purchases, some of them also about dealing with real Apple IDs, but I found none with a really precise answer about the exact behaviour / errors you get, doing so.

### The actual question

I have an app with IAPs, whenever I try to log in using my real Apple ID, and the app is asking for products / prices or trying to buy something, I get the following error popups.

- Entering the valid password
  [image]
- Entering a wrong password
  [image]
- Already logged in when starting the app (in `Settings` => `iTunes & App Store`)
  [image]

Can someone please confirm (or refute) this to be the expected behaviour?

### To summarize the question(s)

- Is it correct, that real Apple IDs only work in distribution signed apps (for/from the AppStore) and won't work in development signed apps?
- Sandbox Accounts work in a Sandbox Environment no matter how the app was signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct, that real Apple IDs only work in distribution signed
>   apps (for/from the AppStore) and won't work in development signed
>   apps?

Yes. You can't use real apple IDs' in your sandbox environment.

> Sandbox Accounts work in a Sandbox Environment no matter how the app
>   was signed?

Test users created under your account will work with the development build. It won't work with production builds which are downloaded from Appstore.

P.S. You can use a dummy email to create sandbox testers (not sure whether it still works :) )

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW10

Answer (score 2):

When I implemented iAP last month I got exactly the same experience. It all worked perfectly once the app was signed and released on AppStore so you should be safe.

The sandbox account works only in a sandbox environment and will not work if you download the app from the AppStore.